# I cannot delete one text message at a time

Tags: iphone

In iOS 8, I can't delete one single text. I can delete the whole conversation, but not a single text.

Answer (score 1):

THe method changed with IOS 8.

Hold you finger on the message, and when the "copy | more" bubble appears then pick "more".  THen you will see how to delete one message.